# React - Memoising static component - is that an antipattern?

Tags: reactjs, memo

The question might seem strange. However. sometimes for clearer composition I create component which is purely static. No props. Is in this case use of React.memo() an antipattern or it gives any benefits?

Comment: Please provide some code examples :)

Answer (score 0):

It's not an anti-pattern. Even if the component has no properties it can rerender if the parent component rerenders. So if you profiled your application and decided that applying memoization is beneficial to this component then you can use it even if the component has no properties.